# Retain parent state when opening modal in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have written code like

```
.state('articles', {
      parent : 'root',
      url: "/articles/:articleId",
      onEnter: function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: "views/art.html",
            controller: "articlesCtrl",
             size: 'lg'
        }).result.finally(function() {
            $state.transitionTo('^');
        });
    }      

    })
```

It opens modal with url like articles/123. But i want the url to be same as parent. I mean to say user can click from anywhere, but parent should not change. just it should a modal opened. How do i achieve it.

Comment: In that case no need to create separate state for modal window, you can simply call the `$modal.open` method from parent controller itself.

Comment: @vpsingh016 - Or is there a way i can change  $state.transitionTo('^'); to something which will take user to page from where he had clicked the page?

Comment: you can inject `$modalInstance` as dependency in your modal window controller and call the `$modalInstance.close()` when you want to close the modal window. It will redirect to parent page